# How to display data value according to dropdown in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7

I have a table in my database which has a field `lis_type` and the field has 2 values: `sale` and `rent`, and I am calling data on my view page. Let's suppose I click on the Sale page, there only `sale similar listing` should be displayed. If I click on `Rent` then `similar listing` should be shown for `rent`. However, right now both listings are coming together, Please let me guide where I am making a mistake.

**Controller**

```php
public function listingshownow(Request $r, $slug)
{
    $listview = Listing::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $products = Listing::where('propId', $listview->propId)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('lis_type', '=', 'sale')->orWhere('lis_type', '=', 'rent');
        })->get();

    return view('listings-view', compact('products'));
}
```

**View for Similar Listings...**

```php
@foreach($products as $prod)
    @if($prod->lis_type === 'sale')
        <div class="row featured portfolio-items">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 homes-content pb-0 mb-44">
                <ul class="homes-list clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>{{$prod->ls_fs}}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>{{$prod->bathroom}} Bathroom</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a variable to your controller to indicate what kind of page you are viewing, so you can use that in your query/filter.

For example, let's say your sales page URL looks like `http://example.com/listings/sales`.  Then you could set up a route like:

```
Route::get('listings/{type}', 'ListingsController@show');
```

Now your `ListingsController` could have a method like:

```
// The $type parameter will be what was matched in the route
public function show($type) {
    $listings = Listings::where('lis_type', $type)->get();
    return view('listings-view', ['listings' => $listings]);
}
```

You might want to check that `$type` only matches the values you expect.  You could either do that in the controller, eg:

```
// At the top of show()
if ($type !== 'sales' && $type !== 'rent') {
    abort(404);
}
```

Or you could restrict it in your route, by specifying that the `{type}` there has to match some pattern:

```
Route::get('listings/{type}', 'ListingsController@show')->where('type', 'sales|rent');
```

All of this is covered in the [Laravel routing docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing), I suggest reading them, and better yet, take some minutes and browse all the docs! 30min skimming will give you a broad idea of how things work, and the knowledge of where to look and read more when you need a question answered.